# "unloading" or "landing"? The action to remove goods from a ship

Tags: synonyms

When I was checking an English document written by Japanese colleague, I found "landing" and wanted to replace it with "unloading". In Japanese-English dictionary I found "landing" also has such a meaning. But is "landing" actually used in this context?
The goods to be removed are uninstalled voyage equipment.

Comment: I've never heard it, but then I've never worked in the shipping industry.  But note that "lade" is a meaningful term, meaning the action of loading a ship, or (as "lading") the cargo loaded.

Comment: Cargo and passengers can be *landed*, i.e. they are the "contents" of the ship, and brought from the ship to the land,  A ship can be *loaded* and *unloaded*.  The contents of a ship can also be *loaded* and *unloaded*, although usually this refers to things, not to people, unless the people are lacking in agency, e.g. soldiers, prisoners, etc.   In contrast, *landing* a ship means bringing the ship itself to land.  It seems to me that **loading** and **unloading** are the more general terms.  However, they put the focus on the goods as opposed to where they are going, which may be good or bad

Comment: @GlobalCharm Now I understand that "landing" can also work in this case, in a procedure to remove voyage equipment to be reused in another vessel. So I"ll leave it as is. Thank you!

Comment: @GlobalCharm, that should be an answer.